Why is it called Lashon Hara?
Why is it called לשון הרע, the bad language, as opposed to לשון רע, simply bad language? Wouldn’t the latter be more grammatically correct and more pashut?

Probably the definite article is left over from the original source of the term, which is talking about a specific act of speech, the slander of the spies. See Mishna Arachin 3:5

@RabbiKaii great observation. Perhaps then the fact that we continue to call it that indicates that all lashon hara is due to that initial lashon hara told by the spies?
